# Alternative to scripting.filesystemobject in Powershell

Tags: powershell, automation, devops

In my powershell script, I am trying to delete temp folder with

$fso = New-Object -ComObject scripting.filesystemobject

After successfully delete it and when recreate the same folder with script it's keeping old file in it and not deleting it. is there any alternative to this problem?

```
$fso = New-Object -ComObject scripting.filesystemobject

try {
    # recreate tmp path
    If (Test-Path $tmpPath) {           
        $fso.DeleteFolder($tmpPath)
    }

    New-Item -ItemType Directory -Path $tmpPath -Force | Out-Null
    
     
} Catch {
    Write-EventLog 
    return
}
```

Comment: `Remove-Item -LiteralPath $tmpPath` comes to mind

Comment: Problem is it's deleting temp folder but not deleting registry file inside it. whenever I recreate the same folder it keep old registry file which should be deleted once the folder is deleted.

Comment: `Remove-Item -LiteralPath $tmpPath -Force -Recurse` then

Comment: _"Problem is it's deleting temp folder but not deleting registry file inside it."_ - How does that make sense? You can't delete a folder if there is still a file in it, which you can't delete . Please clarify.

Comment: @zett42 I am trying to delete complete folder with files inside it, But idk for what reason with this script folder was getting deleted successfully but the same new folder was being created with updated time It is keeping old registry file in it.

Comment: Still hard to imagine. IMO it's more likely that the registry file is being recreated in the temp folder, for whatever reason.